# Is labelFunction useless with a heirarchical AdvandedDataGrid?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

The signature for labelFunction is:

myLabelFunction(item:Object, column:DataGridColumn):String

where item contains the DataGrid item object, and column specifies the DataGrid column. So with flat data you can get the value you need to format with item[column.dataField].

However with heirarchical data you are given the whole "folder" - i.e. all the items in the heirarchy - in the item parameter so how can you choose which one to use?

Eg. with weather data organized heirarchically by state groups

```
Arizona - maxTemp - Jan, Feb, March, April
Arizona - minTemp - Jan, Feb, March, April
California - maxTemp - Jan, Feb, March, April
California - minTemp - Jan, Feb, March, April
```

If you want to format this, you'll be given the entire Arizona item with a children array containing both maxTemp and minTemp data, there is no way to tell whether you are formatting maxTemp or minTemp. Or is there???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wait... it seems to work after all. I don't get it but anyway item[column.dataField] works.